# What is the exact purpose of `mask` in file system ACL?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, umask

When I apply default ACL in a directory I see `default:mask` or just `mask` in the following two scenario.

**Scenario 1**

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -ld test/
 drwxr-x---. 2 test test 4096 Oct 15 19:12 test/

-bash-4.2$ setfacl -d -m u:arif:rwx test/

-bash-4.2$ getfacl --omit-header test
 user::rwx
 group::r-x
 other::---
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:arif:rwx
 default:group::r-x
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::---
```

**Scenario 2**

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -dl dir/
 drwxr-x---. 2 test test 4096 Oct 15 18:17 dir/

-bash-4.2$ getfacl dir
 # file: dir
 # owner: test
 # group: test
 user::rwx
 group::r-x
 other::---

-bash-4.2$ setfacl -m user:arif:rwx dir

-bash-4.2$ getfacl --omit-header dir
 user::rwx
 user:arif:rwx
 group::r-x
 mask::rwx
 other::---
```

So what is the purpose of `mask` here?

Comment: The sole reason for the mask is to support apps which are not aware of acls.  Maybe this link helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147502/29483

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## What

This 3-bit ACL system has its roots in TRUSIX.  Other ACL systems, such as the  NFS4-style ones in FreeBSD, MacOS, AIX, Illumos, and Solaris, work differently and this concept of a *mask* access control entry is not present.

The *mask* is, as the name says, a mask that is applied to *mask out* permissions granted by access control entries for users and groups.  It is the maximum permission that may be granted by any acccess control entry, other than by a file owner or an "other" entry.  Its 3 bits are `and`ed with the 3 bits of these other entries.

So, for example, if a user is granted `rw-` by an access control entry, but the mask is `r--`, the user will only actually have `r--` access.  Conversely, if a user is only granted `--x` by an access control entry, a mask of `rwx` does not grant extra permissions and the user has just `--x` access.

The *default mask* on a parent directory is the mask setting that is applied to things that are created within it.  It is a form of inheritance.

## Why

It's a shame that IEEE 1003.1e never became a standard and was withdrawn in 1998. In practice, nineteen years on, it's a standard that a wide range of operating systems — from [Linux](http://linux.die.net./man/5/acl) through [FreeBSD](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acl&sektion=3) to [Solaris](http://shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman2/acl.2.html) (alongside the NFS4-style ACLs in the latter cases) — actually implement.

[IEEE 1003.1e working draft #17](https://simson.net/ref/1997/posix_1003.1e-990310.pdf) makes for interesting reading, and I recommend it. In appendix B § 23.3 the working group provides a detailed, eight page, rationale for the somewhat complex way that POSIX ACLs work with respect to the old `S_IRWXG` group permission flags.  (It's worth noting that the TRUSIX people provided much the same analysis ten years earlier.)  This covers the raison d'être for the mask, which I will only précis here.

- Traditional Unix applications expect to be able to deny all access to a file, named pipe, device, or directory with `chmod(…,000)`. In the presence of ACLs, this only turns off *all* user and group permissions if there is a mask and the old `S_IRWXG` maps to it. Without this, setting the old file permissions to `000` wouldn't affect any non-owner `user` or `group` entries and other users would, surprisingly, still have access to the object.

  Temporarily changing a file's permission bits to no access with `chmod 000` and then changing them back again was an old file locking mechanism, used before Unixes gained advisory locking mechanisms, that [— as you can see — people still use even in the 21st century](http://prabindatta-myownblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/lock-folderdirectory.html).  (Advisory locking has been easily usable from scripts with portable well-known tools such as `setlock` since the late 1990s.)
- Traditional Unix scripts expect to be able to run `chmod go-rwx` and end up with only the object's owner able to access the object.  Again, this doesn't work unless there is a mask and the old `S_IRWXG` permissions map to it; because otherwise that `chmod` command wouldn't turn off any non-owner `user` or `group` access control entries, leading to users other than the owner and non-owning groups retaining access to something that *is expected* to be accessible *only* to the owner.

  And again [— as you can see — this sort of `chmod` command was still the received wisdom](http://washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html) twelve years later. The rationale still holds.
- Other approaches without a mask mechanism have flaws.
- An alternative system where the permission bits were otherwise separate from and `and`ed with the ACLs would require file permission flags to be `rwxrwxrwx` in most cases, which would confuse the heck out of the many Unix applications that complain when they see what they think to be world-writable stuff.
- An alternative system where the permission bits were otherwise separate from and  `or`ed with the ACLs would have the `chmod(…,000)` problem mentioned before.

Hence an ACL system with a mask.

## Further reading

- Craig Rubin (1989-08-18).  [*Rationale for Selecting Access Control List Features for the Unix System*](http://fas.org./irp/nsa/rainbow/tg020-a.htm).  NCSC-TG-020-A.  DIANE Publishing.  ISBN 9780788105548.
- Portable Applications Standards Committee of the IEEE Computer Society (October 1997).
  [*Draft Standard for Information Technology—Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX)—Part 1: System Application Program Interface (API)— Amendment #: Protection, Audit and Control Interfaces [C Language]*](http://simson.net/ref/1997/posix_1003.1e-990310.pdf)  IEEE 1003.1e.  Draft 17.
- Winfried Trümper (1999-02-28).  [*Summary about Posix.1e*](http://wt.tuxomania.net/publications/posix.1e/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406545/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235284/5132
- [How can I grant owning group permissions when POSIX ACLs are applied?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394018/)
- [Performing atomic write operations in a file in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274498/)

Comment: And for this reason it is not a bad idea to set up a mask other than rwx. BTW: If you `chmod 0` a file with ACLs, the mask is set to 0. If you later call e.g. `chmod 664 file`, the mask is set to the maximum of group and other bits which is 6 in this case.

Comment: How the mask is updated I think to be worthy of a Q&A in its own right.

Comment: BTW: The POSIX-1003.1 draft for ACLs has been withdrawn in 1997 by the reference implementations (a.g. Solaris) because it turned out that customers wanted a more powerful method that has later been standardized as NVSv4 ACLs.