# Why was POSIX.1e withdrawn?

Tags: posix, history, acl

The proposed POSIX.1e standard defines a few things like ACLs that are widely supported.  But the proposal itself was withdrawn.  How come?  The only reasoning I've found online is this quote from http://wt.tuxomania.net/topics/1999_06_Posix_1e/:

> Why Posix.1e was abandoned is difficult to understand from today's
>   (July 2014) point of view. Solaris, Irix, Linux, and probably other
>   Unices seemed to recognize the standard. On the other hand the FreeBSD
>   project found counter arguments and didn't integrate capabilities
>   ('fine grained privileges') by default.

On the other hand, Jörg Schilling said this on this site ([What is the exact purpose of `mask` in file system ACL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475698/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-mask-in-file-system-acl/475796#comment869707_475796))

> BTW: The POSIX-1003.1 draft for ACLs has been withdrawn in 1997 by the
>   reference implementations (a.g. Solaris) because it turned out that
>   customers wanted a more powerful method that has later been
>   standardized as NVSv4 ACLs.

Is there a more detailed account of what happened?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I seem to have hit paydirt here. I searched the "usual haunts" and found nada, then thought, hey, where in the good 'ole days would *NIX freaks post about this stuff?

Usenet. They would post on Usenet. On April 30, 2002, Casey Schauffler [wrote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/Posix.1e$20withdrawn/comp.security.unix/gfyLMetqubs/5tBrcPuJA0gJ):

> I was the final technical editor of the document,
>   and had the unpleasant task of requesting its withdrawl after
>   the completion of Draft 17.
>
> In the end, only SGI and IBM cared enough about it to continue
>   working on it, IBM would not pay for travel, and twice in
>   Poughkeepsie was all I could handle.
>
> More to the point, standards development fell off
>   of the list of important things for computer companies
>   right about 1995, and the security effort fell victem
>   to that.
>
> There where a number of issues with the Draft itself that
>   didn't help. It should have been five seperate efforts
>   (ACLs, Audit, Capabilities, Information Labels, MAC)
>   rather that a single integrated document. The source
>   for the draft disappeared for a year and was only
>   partially recovered. Some sections where too ambitious
>   for their intended purpose. Too much was designed by
>   the working group.

Comment: impressive sleuthing.  USENET is a beast from the past, although some of us still use it. :)